# Restart NOOBS downloading process?

Tags: noobs

I was at university with NOOBS in SD card and my Raspberry. I need to install OpenELEC which is downloaded from Internet. However, it seems that university cable network doesn't provide DHCP or something, and I need to set an static IP manually.

So, NOOBS tells "Error downloading distribution lists" because I don't have Internet.

I've managed to set an static IP by logging into tty2 as root, and editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/resolv.conf`. It works, as I've already tried the built-in browser that comes with NOOBS. However, I can't restart the NOOBS download list process, and if I reboot Raspberry Pi, I loose my network changes.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I haven't ever used the NOOBS software, so I may not be the most qualified to answer, but you *should* be able to edit the file manually before you copy the NOOBS .zip onto the SD card. I'll check when I get home, but it should work in theory.

Comment: I should also need to check if those files live freely in the NOOBS files.

Comment: *"I loose my network changes"* -> Not if you mean the edits you made to `interfaces`, etc.

Comment: From what I remember, after rebooting Pi I would have lost my `interfaces` edits.. I couldn't managed to set an static IP and keep it after rebooting

Comment: I'd like to try it again to be more sure about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question and/or configuration clearly. If you edit a file on the SD the editing will stay on the next boot, however, after booting you are starting a different O/S they will not prevail. Looks that this is your case. Very unlikely a campus will have no DHCP: most probably they request you to register the MAC address, you are sneaking into the network entering a random valid IP, that at one point, may collide with another valid user. How do you connect to TTY2? Are you using PuTTY (SSH) or using a serial cable on TXD/RXD UART? How did you download OpenELEC? How